# Как изменить вывод

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
from transformers import pipeline
        
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model="sberbank-ai/rugpt3large_based_on_gpt2")
results = generator("Что подарить мужчине спортсмену на день рождения 19 лет?", max_length = 25)
print(results)
```

Вывод:

```py
[{'generated_text': 'Что подарить мужчине спортсмену на день рождения 19 лет?\nПодари ему что-нибудь из спортивного инвентаря.<s>'}]
```

Как сделать, чтобы `'generated_text'` не выводило?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `pipeline` возвращает вам не строку, а *список словарей*. Получить первый сгенерированный текст можно так:

```py
results = generator("Что подарить мужчине спортсмену на день рождения 19 лет?", max_length = 25)
generated_text = results[0]['generated_text']
print(generated_text)
```

***stdout:***

```py
Что подарить мужчине спортсмену на день рождения 19 лет?
Подари ему что-нибудь из спортивного инвентаря.<s>
```